# range based for-loop on r-value

Tags: c++, syntax, c++17, syntactic-sugar

The following does not behave as i would like it too, as the destructor of Foo is called before the range-based for loop enters the body making the iterators invalid (msvc 2019).

Is there a way to "capture" the Foo object within without changing the syntax in the following code? I have seen the c++20 initializer part of the for loop, but if there is an alternative solution which does not need it, that would be preferred.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo& operator<<(std::string s) { ...; return *this }

    auto begin() {...}
    auto end() {...}
}   

for (auto& row : Foo() << "bar")
{
    // this fails because destructor of Foo is already called
    // how to extend the lifetime of the Foo object into the scope of the for loop?
}
```

Comment: Long story short, no.  Lifetime extension of temporaries does not extend through a function call (which is what `operator <<` is)

Comment: @NathanOliver
I was thinking something in the direction of 
`Foo operator<<(std::string s) && { ...; return std::move(*this); }`
(But didn't get it working yet) does that seem potentially a solution?

Comment: Like I said, temporaries don't live through a function call.  There is no way around that.  Since you want to use `Foo() << "bar"`, that can't be accomplished.  You *could* make a constructor that calls your `operator <<`, and then your syntax would become `for (auto& row : Foo("bar"))`.

Comment: @NathanOliver In my example in the comment above, I move the temporary Foo, and return the new version. The now empty object will, as you say, not live through the function call, but that shouldn't matter?

Comment: I missed you were returning by value.  That should actually work.  Might want to ask a new question with the function implemented like that but make sure to provide a [mre] if it's giving you errors/unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what your `operator<<` returns.

Remember that behind the scene, your range-based for loop basically produce a code like this:

```
auto && __range = Foo() << "bar" ; 
auto __begin = __range.begin() ;
auto __end = __range.end() ;
for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) 
{ 
    auto& row = *__begin;
    ... loop_statement 
}
```

The problem with this code is that your `operator<<` returns a reference to a temporary object. In order to assign it to `__range`, it must be returned by value.

Assuming your `Foo` class is basically a wrapper of an `std::vector`, and `operator<<` just pushback an object to that vector, then you can do things like:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() : vec{} {}
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    auto begin() { return vec.begin();}
    auto end() { return vec.end();}
};

auto operator<<(Foo&& foo, std::string s)
{
    foo.vec.emplace_back(std::move(s));
    return std::move(foo);
}

auto& operator<<(Foo& foo, std::string s)
{
    foo.vec.emplace_back(std::move(s));
    return foo;
}
```

Here two overload of the non-member function `operator<<` were created, with each of them being called depends on if `foo` was a temporary object.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6v3rv4xYs)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Foo` object just instantly "dies". You have several options. For example make `Foo` static or create instance of `Foo` before the for loop.